# Flagging a whole comment thread as obsolete

Tags: discussion, comments, flags

If a whole comment thread has become obsolete (for example, if the question has been clarified or if the discussion results have been included in an answer), should I

- delete all my own comments and flag all the others as *obsolete* individually (which is a bit boring, since you can only delete/flag one comment every five seconds), or
- flag a single one of the comments as "*other...*" and describe the situation?

What do the moderators prefer?

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182684

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If the entire comment thread is obsolete, then you can flag the question/answer using "Other" and explain that all the comments are obsolete and should be deleted.  We have an easy way to purge all comments from a single post.

It is much easier to use a single flag than flagging each individual comment.

Comment flags go into a different queue and it is possible that a single comment could get deleted without purging the entire obsolete conversation, so flagging the post would be better.