# Why was my "purge comments" flag declined?

Tags: support, status-completed, comments, declined-flags

I've flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313970/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lower-case/313988#313988) with an *Other* flag with the following explanation:

> obsolete/non constructive comment thread - only the last comment carries important information

However, the flag was declined with the following explanation:

> Flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

Comments eligible for removal fall into the category of *content that requires moderator intervention*, according to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254854/2642204).

Thus I'm confused - what went wrong? Should I stop flagging posts with unnecessary comment threads?

Comment: At most you could have been a bit more specific about why exactly it's obsolete or non-constructive. But yeah, nothing much there that needs to be preserved imho.

Comment: At a glance, the very first comment provides a link to documentation, which I would consider constructive. I would forgive a time-pressed moderator for seeing that and thinking "meh, looks okay." As Bart said, you should be more specific in your flag message about why the Boost vs. no Boost argument is not constructive. You get 200 characters for "other" comment flags...use them.

Comment: I don't get the point of deleting those comments.  If you take a dependency on a library then having some awareness of the consequences is useful.  They are not mentioned in the post at all, clearly you can fix that if you can edit without bias.

Comment: @HansPassant IIRC this kind of edit would be "changing the original meaning", so only the author could do that. Beside, I'd expect the fact that using library X makes you take a dependency on X (duh) be a common knowledge. Otherwise all answers recommending a solution using some 3rd party lib would have to contain a warning "hey you know, using X will make you dependent on X"...

Comment: BartoszKP, that's not what @HansPassant was saying at all; he talked about the importance of *knowing the consequences* of taking a dependency on a library (hence the value in keeping those comments). he treated "taking a dependency" as a given.

Comment: @WillNess Still it's hard to imagine that every answer using some 3rd party library should contain explanations regarding "the importance of knowing the consequences of taking a dependency"

Comment: hmm? the comments in question don't talk about the importance of knowing the consequences at all. they discuss the consequences themselves. of course these consequences should be discussed only if they are pertinent to the answer given. to pass a judgment on that, knowledge of the subject matter is necessary. i.e. the answer uses boost, and if this usage entails some important caveats, it seems they should be mentioned, and if there are no caveats in this specific case, *then* the boost discussion would be out of place there.

Comment: @WillNess Well, I wanted to discuss which *particular* caveats (compilation time? every additional header with templates increases compilation time...) - but seems comments have been purged. Including the one that was important, and which I explicitly indicated in my flag comment.... :|

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comments have been purged. Including the one that was *important*, and which I explicitly indicated in my flag comment.... :|

Comment: Another data point confirming my assumption that mod deletion of comments sucks for everybody involved. A bit of cleanup is probably not worth it if important information is lost as collateral damage. It has been repeatedly stated that the mod interface for comment flags (and probably comment deletion in general) is severely lacking, hopefully that will be fixed and improves the current situation. But maybe SE should rethink the whole mantra that comments are inherently temporary and nobody should complain if they're deleted without trace, no matter the contents.