# What's the best way to accept correction in a comment thread?

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette

This is a question I have about etiquette here:

Suppose someone asks a question and I post a "maybe you could try X?" comment, or some other advice underneath. Then someone else comes along and correctly points out that X wouldn't work for whatever reason, or is based on a flawed assumption or a misunderstanding of the question, and I recognize their criticism to be correct. What is the best way to respond?

I could:

- **Do nothing** This is the easiest option but the person who corrected it might expect or appreciate a reply to their criticism.
- **Just delete my wrong-headed comment and slink off quietly, being more careful before commenting next time.** This removes poor quality content but leaves an orphan comment (the one replying to it). Also, information about why certain naive solutions are actually a bad idea could be useful in some circumstances and will be more clear if the whole comment thread is intact.
- **Post a quick "Ah yes, you're right, I stand corrected." note** It's always nice when people acknowledge they are wrong (especially since that can be a rarity on the Internet), but perhaps this falls foul of the "no chatty/I-agree comments" rule.
- **Something else?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My personal preference:

- Post a quick "Ah yes, you're right, I stand corrected." note.

Then you make a decision:

- If your misconception is a common one, I would leave it at that. It prevents others from making the same mistake that you did. Your second comment ("I stand corrected") is important, because it immediately tells readers that the other person was right and they don't have to re-evaluate whether the criticism was justified.
- Otherwise:

  - Wait a while to give the other user a chance to read your comment.
  - Return, delete your two comments and flag the other user's comment as obsolete. (Alternatively, [flag the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254853/87698) with a note that all comments are obsolete and can be removed.)