# Appropriate sequence of actions for comments deletion when helping a user

Tags: discussion

I try to help *novice* users who misuse a tag and could miss their target audience by commenting their question with a text I prepared in advance.

Example for a question about `Parse.com` where the user tagged `parsing` instead (and the question is not about parsing, otherwise I wouldn't do this):

> `parsing`: this tag isn't for questions about the hosted service Parse.com, please edit your question and use "parse.com" instead. Thank you.

Once the OP has edited the question, I delete my comment. Until now, all is fine.

If the OP posts a comment like

> ok, I did it

I delete my comment and I flag theirs as `obsolete`.

But when the user comments like

> sorry for the mistake! my bad I'm new here! :(

I feel like I can't just clean the room and go away, so I also comment

> Don't worry. Thank you for editing your question!

or something like that, and I come back later to delete and flag obsolete (if there's a thread in the making I often forget to [flag just one comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254853/flagging-a-whole-comment-thread-as-obsolete) at the end of the discussion and I flag step by step instead).

Sometimes if I notice it's their very first intervention it's more like

> Thank you for editing your question! And welcome to SO! To get better help, you can read The Tour, and ... ...

but I'm not sure about any of this because now I'm creating a discussion in the comments that I'm going to flag as obsolete minutes later and it seems awkward.

**Is it ok? Is this a proper way of handling these sequences of events?**

I'm inclined to think that it's a lot of noise for nothing and I shouldn't do this - and on the other hand I want to help the user understand they should do X instead of Y.

Because this is a specific situation about a recurring misuse of some tags by novice users, and I've noticed that if I just edit myself they can use the wrong tag again later.

For every other situation I always edit the post myself without asking OP to do anything.

Comment: I don't see any reason to not edit the tags yourself.  If you *really* want to post a comment explaining why you've made the change you can, but you can just put that text in the revision history as well, which is exactly what its there for.

Comment: I think you are trying too hard.

Comment: @KevinB You may be right. It's a new habit, and I was happy with it until recently. Then I thought that it wasn't actually useful. It may help one person from time to time how to use the tag features, but... well, I wasn't sure anymore.

Comment: well, it's a nice gesture, and i'm sure the op appreciates it, i just hope it doesn't give the wrong impression. The comments in particular aren't really "useful", they're just friendly. what irks me about it is this isn't a forum or a social network, and i'd hate for the OP to mistakenly think SO works like either. But maybe i'm thinking too much into it.

Comment: You are both right, I should probably just paste my text snippet in the revision history - and only add a comment when the user doesn't notice it, does a mistake again later or doesn't understand how the tags work. No need for more noise in the comments.

Comment: In the past, whenever I spotted a [statistics question with a tag `pdf`](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33425353/1) I patiently explained that "[tag:pdf] is for Adobe's Portable Document File". I stopped doing that when I realized it's clearly mentioned in the tag description. It could warrant a comment "y u not readin tag descriptions?" but simply removing it is way more easier on the ol' blood pressure.

Comment: @Jongware Spot on. I agree.

Comment: Well thank you! But I feel it's not really a good answer to your question. Rather than addressing the issue (i.e., "People Do Not Tag Correctly") I circumvent it, not by teaching the hapless user to *please be courteous and read the rules!* but using my Immediate-Edit privilege (> 2K) to force them to. It's still possible the OP (or (heavens forbid!) someone else) decides to add the tag again.

Comment: Yeah, I changed that part of my comment. I just liked the way it was put but it wouldn't be that good as an answer, you're right.

Comment: ... with careless attitudes like that I always think of proposing having to fill in a "Pop Quiz Hotshot!" *mandatory* before a question can be asked ...

Comment: (Minor addition to my first comment) I was delighted to find I could edit tags immediately but I just read that comes free with >10K rep. >2K rep unlocks unmoderated editing, and then one would typically leave a comment such as "removed irrelevant tag". -Just FYI for lesser rep editors.

Comment: I got 10k recently and to this date, even after thousands of edits, reviews, answers and comments, I'm still not sure when/how to use all my super powers. I have so many doubts, ahah. I guess I will figure it out eventually...

Comment: If your interaction with a new user ends up generating a series of comments that are no longer needed try to get them to delete their comments by posting a final comment like "Ok, now that we've got that resolved, let's delete these comments". Give them a few minutes to see your comment and then start deleting. I find that strategy generally works, and it avoids bothering the mods with trivia.

Comment: Or you could just _not delete the comments_, and preserve the historical record.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possible protocol - upvote comment (as acknowledge that you've seen it) and move on. Do not thank for thanks and edits (remove downvote/upvote if appropriate).

I never considered comments on re-tagging edits - information about tag usage should be in the tag and if OP really want to tag perfectly they'll read it. Otherwise re-tagging is generally 3-10 seconds operation for 2K+ users and by itself provide enough information (if OP pays attention).

Unless you expect question to become canonical or at least popular I don't think there is value in cleaning up comments. Otherwise - flag other comments obsolete and move on. In rare cases when question deserve more efforts - consider flagging with "other:remove all comments/remove all comments after this as obsolete".

Before deleting comments take into account:

- if you've already added guidance comment no one else need to spend time doing the same.  Removing such comment can waste time of multiple people.
- if your comment explains edit - consider if later OP will complain "some #@#@# changed all my question" - good visible comment would keep you sane.

Note: If you find yourself providing similar comments a lot - find app on https://stackapps.com/ to auto-fill comments that suits your needs.

Comment: Upvoting such a comment doesn’t feel right to me, because comments should be upvoted if they add something useful to the post. “Sorry, I’ve edited it” doesn’t really add anything useful.

Comment: I agree with @Xufox. Also, there is no way for OP to know who upvoted the comment. It is a quite subtle signal to send to someone who is new to the site.

Comment: I like it. No problem if the OP doesn't know who upvoted their comment, *if the OP is a novice* I think it's a nice signal to them, it's a silent "thank you for doing things right". // But I've accepted this mostly because it made sense for me. Sentences like "Do not thank for thanks" helped me understand I was overzealous in my actions. // If anyone wants to add a different answer I'll be all ears but I'm already convinced to stop posting these comments, it just adds noise and wastes everybody's time.

Comment: @Xufox - agree, but I see  no other ways to acknowledge OP's action when *you want to* (in case you can't change vote). Upvote comment and flag "too chatty" at the same time may be better (since votes on comments are rate limited I'd not worry too much - one would eventually figure out where they votes should be spent)