# What is the correct procedure for handling large amounts of trashy comments on a post?

Tags: support, flags, comments, comment-flags

There have been many times when I come across a useful and well written answer, and find multiple "Thank you!", or "This works!", or "This is the one true answer", type of comments.

By "multiple", I mean that I've seen up to as many as 10 of these useless comments on a single post.

Just a *minor* example can be seen here:

> [image]

I know that the correct procedure when coming across "thank you!" comments is to flag them as "Not constructive" or "Too chatty", and I have done that. But what should I do if there are 10 garbage comments on a single post?

Flagging all of them individually seems like it may be irritating for the mods who would have to handle it (if not irritating for me), but flagging one just one comment doesn't alert them to the fact that there are more of the same type of comments.

There was one time when I decided to raise a custom flag on a garbage comment, and wrote that there were many others on the same post. The comment that I flagged was deleted, but the rest were left on the post.

So what would be the best way to alert a moderator that there are many garbage comments on a post? Flag individually?

Comment: I'm surprised not to see machine learning algorithms in place to filter and notify users that their comment is "chatty" prior to even being allowed to post it. By now there has got to be a good training set of previously flagged/removed comments from which the algorithm can learn..

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I have had good results by flagging all applicable comments.  My understanding is that moderators see them en-bloc and can deal with them as a group (*[confirmed by meagar ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322702/what-is-the-correct-procedure-for-handling-large-amounts-of-trashy-comments-on-a?cb=1#comment342532_322739)*).

Also, if enough people flag a comment, it gets deleted automatically with no moderator intervention.  This cannot happen if you're flagging the top-level post.

Comment: This please. Flag the individual comments as "too chatty" rather than issuing an "other" flag on the post itself. It makes it much easier for us. It generates more flags, but the flags are better categorized and more easily actionable with less thought on the part of the moderator. It's very easy to validate a "Too chatty" flag on an obviously bad comment without leaving the flag queue, where if you flag the post I have to load the post in a new tab, expand the comments, dredge through them for the bad ones, delete them individually, etc etc.

Comment: @meagar I notice if I flag a whole number of comments on one post, they group together in my flag history. Do you see them like that on your end?

Comment: @Laurel yes, we see them batched together under the post they belong to, and we can smash through them in a few seconds

Comment: One more reason you should flag the comments: If a number of people (three? five? not sure off hand) flag a comment it gets automatically deleted with no moderator intervention. This cannot happen if you're flagging the top-level post.

Comment: @meagar I've folded your comments into the question.

Comment: That rate limit, though...

Comment: _"we can smash through them in a few seconds"_ I'm not convinced that's a good thing.

Comment: Argh, this bullshit again. The mods have been divided on this for as long as I've been on Stack Exchange, and never speak to each other about it or publicly acknowledge the disagreement. Here @meager says you should flag individual comments and BoltClock expresses no clear preference. Over at http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203211/200582, Shog9 and ChrisF say to do precisely the opposite. I've seen the same question in half a dozen other places, with each mod having their own answer. If they care, they should put forward a unified policy; *whatever* you do now violates some mods' instructions.

Comment: @MarkAmery Also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254853/flagging-a-whole-comment-thread-as-obsolete (found after I posted this answer)

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: Trust me, when it comes to deleting 20-or-30-odd "thanks!" comments, being able to smash through them in a matter of seconds with no rate limits on deletion (ironically...) is incredibly liberating.

Comment: @MarkAmery ChrisF has no answer there, and I don't think Shoq9 is making the categorical statement you think they are.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: I walked right into that one, didn't I.

Comment: @BoltClock: You did.

Comment: *If they care, they should put forward a unified policy* @MarkAmery -  Feature request for a flagging FAQ or update to the help page?

Answer (score -11):

Flag the post itself and explain that there are a lot of comments on that post that merit deletion (and explain why).

Comment: Isn't this likely to lead to ALL comments being deleted, not just the noisy ones?

Comment: @Laurel, I flagged an answer with a lot of garbage comments, lets see what happens.

Comment: @Laurel -  I was able to ask a Moderator to delete an extended conversation between myself and another user without others users' comments getting caught in the crossfire. As long as the OP didn't say to remove all comments, this is probably fine.

Comment: @Laurel That'll depend on context.  It'd depend on whether there are comments worth saving, what your flag message says, and who the mod is.  If you're clear about which comments are problematic, and there really are comments worth saving, then probably not, if there aren't comments worth saving, then that may well be exactly what happens.

Comment: @BSMP Simply delete all of your comments, and flag their comments as obsolete (as they are half of a deleted conversation).

Comment: @Yakk - That conversation has already been taken care of, I was just pointing out that it's possible to get multiple comments deleted without all of the comments being nuked.