# Flagging my own comments, along with comments from another user

Tags: feature-request, comment-flags

In [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322739/3386109) it was suggested that the best course of action for cleaning up multiple comments is to flag each comment separately. To quote the [comment by meagar ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322702/what-is-the-correct-procedure-for-handling-large-amounts-of-trashy-comments-on-a?cb=1#comment342532_322739)

> Flag the individual comments [...] rather than issuing an
>   "other" flag on the post itself. It makes it much easier for us. It
>   generates more flags, but the flags are better categorized and more
>   easily actionable with less thought on the part of the moderator.

So in that spirit, if I want to flag a series of non-constructive comments, I would flag each one individually. However, I would also like to flag my own comments as obsolete. The intent here is two-fold:

1. To give the moderator the full context of the discussion
2. To clean up my comments at the same time that the other user's comments are cleaned up

So my feature request: **allow me to flag my own comments as obsolete**.

Comment: _**allow me to flag my own comments as obsolete**_ Why not just delete them?? That's what I do, and I flag other's comments referring to these as obsolete.

Comment: Because they provide context to the moderator who needs to decide whether my flags on the other user's comments are justified.

Comment: The best way to do this is to use the other flag, and ask the moderator to clean up comment clutter. It's a single flag which can only be handled by a moderator. I've used it several times without a mod complaining about it and without having the flag declined. If your comments provide context that is necessary, then they're not yet obsolete.

Comment: @user3386109 Moderators can see you deleted comments, so for them the context will be clear.

Comment: @KenWhite That's the point. If I understand meagar's comment correctly, the mod will see all of the flags, and hence all of the comments, at once. So they all go at the same time.

Comment: If there are many existing flags, and then you ask the mod to clean up clutter with a custom flag on yours, they can see the other flags and deal with them as well, which was my point. Flag the other posts, flag one of yours asking for cleanup, and let the mod handle it.

Comment: I'm not sure what the moderator sees when the UI presents multiple comment flags en masse. Certainly the moderator can open another window and look at the question. But that seems a waste of time if all the comments, including mine can be presented in a single dialog.

Comment: The mods can apparently see enough. :-) As I said, I've never had a flag declined when asking the mod to clean up clutter, even if I've not flagged any other comment first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Stack Overflow, I'd recommend deleting your own comments and flagging the others that should go. It's easiest to stay in the flag queue and click delete a bunch of times.

If for some reason you *really* want the comments to die together, it's acceptable to flag the post with an 'other' flag explaining that you want them all deleted. It's also acceptable to just flag one of the comments with a custom flag explaining the same. **This should be an exception, not a rule.**

Comment: Ok, will do. Thanks for the quick response.