# Mods' UI: Multiple "No longer needed" flags - LIFO, FIFO, or X don't care?

Tags: support, flags, moderator-tools

If I am flagging several, say ten, comments on a post as "No longer needed," do moderators prefer them to be flagged in any particular order?

For example, the trail may go from requesting information to that information (eventually) being supplied in a comment. So, I could flag the information comment first so that the subsequently flagged comments are obviously precursors to it, *or* I could flag the comments in chronological order.

Does it make any difference for moderators as to how easy they are to process?

And if there are two or more intertwined comment sequences, is there a preference for them to be flagged as if by thread?

Comment: Related: [What is the correct procedure for handling large amounts of trashy comments on a post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322702) (TL;DR, flagging comments individually is the preferred approach, but no order is specified)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The order is completely irrelevant.

I just checked for good measure, and regardless of the order you flag the comments in, provided they're on the same post, they appear in order of when they were posted, *not* in the order in which they were flagged.

The only time the comment mod tools discriminate based on when the flag was raised is when sorting relative to other posts with the same amount of comment flags. Basically, the mod tools sort posts overall by the amount of comments flagged first, and flag order second. There's some more finicky details on the actual sorting system that I won't bore you with, but that's the two main sorting rules.

In either case, post sorting doesn't affect comment sorting. This means you won't be able to provide context by flag order on comments within the same post, so feel free to flag in whatever order you see fit. It's all the same in the mod tools.

It's also all just a long list of comments anyway. Here's a screenshot, with actual details removed, in case you're interested (the button colors are non-standard, for the record):

> [image]

Comment: That's handy to know, as I always hoped I wasn't making someone's modding annoying with my usual LIFO flagging order.

Comment: "I won't bore you with" - please, please do bore us :) If you are at liberty to discuss, this is quite an interesting topic from the technical standpoint.

Comment: @OlegValter I don't think it's super secret, it's just sorting in a dashboard anyway :p The base listing for posts the system otherwise considers "identical priority" or whatever is effectively FIFO, but it's still a list where you can just... pick the last item. I read through the last ones a lot to filter out bad and easy flags for instance. There's a lot of vague details though, it's not exactly listed what the sorting order is. Different types of flags may or may not weigh in, the count of flags weighs more than individual flags for comments at least

Comment: (2 NLN flags on two comments is less "important" than 2 NLN flags on one comment). This may or may not apply to regular posts, but because their sorting already is different, I don't really know. I do doubt it though. The 2 NLN flag in the screenshot outranked a few other posts with two individually flagged NLN comments, though, so it's at least confirmed for comments. From what I can tell, the bulk of the remaining rules just deal with edge-case management, for when the main rules fail